# Laravel 9.42 Facing problems routing to the correct page below is my code instead of saving to db when i press button input fields are cleared

Tags: php, html, laravel-9

When i press the store button instead of posting to the db its clearing the input fileds  when i press the button store the information must be posted to the database and the redirects to the admin.menus.index but when i press the store button the input filelds are only cleraed

My Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Menu;
use App\Models\Category;
use App\Http\Requests\MenuStoreRequest;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class MenuController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $menus = Menu::all();
        return view('admin.menus.index',compact('menus'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {

        $categories = Category::all();
        return view('admin.menus.create',compact('categories'));
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(MenuStoreRequest $request)
    {
        $image = $request->file('image')->store('public/menus');

        Menu::create([
            
            'name' => $request->name,
            'description' => $request->description, 
            'image' => $image,
            'price' => $request->price

        ]);

        return to_route('admin.menus.index');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

My blade file

```
<x-admin-layout>
  <x-slot name="header">
      <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 dark:text-gray-200 leading-tight">
          {{ __('Dashboard') }}
      </h2>
  </x-slot>

  <div class="py-12">
      <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">

          <div class=" flex justify-items-end m-2 p-2">
              <a href="{{ route('admin.menus.index') }}" class="px-4 py-2 bg-indigo-500 hover:bg-indigo-600 rounded-lg text-white">Menus Index</a>
          </div>

          <div class="m-2 p-2 bg-slate-100 rounded">
              <div class="space-y-8 divide-y divide-gray-200 w-1/2 mt-10">
                  <form  method="POST" action="{{ route('admin.menus.store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    @csrf
                  
                    <div class="sm:col-span-6">
                      <label for="name" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700"> Name </label>
                      <div class="mt-1">
                        <input type="text" id="name"  name="name" 
                        class="block w-full  appearance-none bg-white border border-gray-400 rounded-md py-2 px-3 text-base leading-normal transition duration-150 ease-in-out sm:text-sm sm:leading-5" />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sm:col-span-6">
                      <label for="image" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700"> Image </label>
                      <div class="mt-1">
                        <input type="file" id="image" " name="image" class="block w-full  appearance-none bg-white border border-gray-400 rounded-md py-2 px-3 text-base leading-normal transition duration-150 ease-in-out sm:text-sm sm:leading-5" />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sm:col-span-6 pt-5">
                      <label for="body" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">Price</label>
                      <div class="mt-1">
                        <input type="number"  min ="0.00" max ="10000.00" step="0.01" id="price" wire:model.lazy="price" name="price" class="block w-full  appearance-none bg-white border border-gray-400 rounded-md py-2 px-3 text-base leading-normal transition duration-150 ease-in-out sm:text-sm sm:leading-5" />
                      </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="sm:col-span-6 pt-5">
                      <label for="body" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">Description</label>
                      <div class="mt-1">
                        <textarea id="body" rows="3" wire:model.lazy="body" class="shadow-sm focus:ring-indigo-500 appearance-none bg-white border  py-2 px-3 text-base leading-normal transition duration-150 ease-in-out focus:border-indigo-500 block w-full sm:text-sm border-gray-300 rounded-md"></textarea>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="sm:col-span-6 pt-5">
                      <label for="body" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">Categories</label>
                      <div class="mt-1">
                         <select id="categories" name="categories[]" class="form-multiselect block w-full mt-1"
                          multiple>
                           
                            @foreach ($categories as $category)
                            <option>{{ $category->name }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                         </select>
                      </div>
                    </div>


                    
                    <div class="mt-6 p-4">

                      <button type="submit" 
                      class="py-2 px-4  bg-indigo-500 hover:bg-indigo-700 rounded-lg text-white">
                          Store
                      </button>

                    

                    </div>

                  </form>
                </div>
                
          </div>
              

          

          

      </div>
  </div>
</x-admin-layout>
```

My Request

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class MenuStoreRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' =>['required'],
            'description' =>['required'],
            'price' =>['required'],
            'image' =>['required','image'],

        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Validation errors maybe? You don't show them (or use `old()` to show the values entered)

Comment: Your `<textarea>` is missing a `name` attribute. If that was supposed to be the `description` your validation will fail for sure

Comment: (Unrelated) fyi: the `for` attribute in `<label for="body"` is pointing to the textarea above, not the actual categories

Comment: For showing validation errors: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors